# clear data attribute event

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Is there an attribute event for the x on text input with '.form-control' such as onkeyup?
(In the red below):

[image]

Comment: Is the `x` added by the browser, or are you using a JavaScript plugin? A `change` event will be fired when the value is cleared.

Comment: I assumed it was part of the bootstrap `form-control` class but upon removing the class the `x` was still there so it might must be browser.

Comment: @fubar, I tried `onchange = "search()"` but that only works when the user clicks away from the input box

Comment: So you want to call the `search()` function when the text input value is cleared?

Comment: well I want to return it to the original state, which is what happens on search with empty input. But like I mentioned, onchange only triggers after clicking away from the input box.

Comment: Interesting. What browser are you using, that adds the `x` button?

Comment: both chrome and IE...I might just disable it and only update data onkeyup.

Comment: I've tried on Chrome 63 and the latest MS Edge, and I don't get the `x` button when using `input.form-control`. Without being able to reproduce it, I can't help.